# Port Audio process stereo

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

I am new to PortAudio. I am using it with a C++ Wrapper header.

http://sdr.f4gkr.org/trac/browser/gkSDR/Logiciel/audio/pawrapper.h?rev=5

I need to know about what should do to be able to take stereo input and break it down into two separate channels.

I am inputting from one channel by this code.

```
  inputStreamParam.channelCount = 2;
  inputStreamParam.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
  inputStreamParam.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
  inputStreamParam.suggestedLatency = suggestedLatency;
  inputStreamParam.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

  if(outputStreamParam.device > 0)
    sampleRate = getDefaultSampleRate(outputStreamParam.device);
  else
    sampleRate = 44100.0;

  frameLength = 1024; //set to a useful value

int paWrapper::startAudio(void)
{
  if(isRunning) return pawErrorAudioIsRunning;
  isRunning=true;
  err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream,
                      &inputStreamParam,
                      &outputStreamParam,
                      sampleRate,
                      frameLength,
                      paNoFlag,
                      &paWrapper::paStaticCallback,
                      this);

  if(err != paNoError)
  {
    isRunning=false;
    return err;
  }
  int err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
  if(err != paNoError)
    isRunning=false;
  return err;
}
```

How should I modify to be able to acquire two channels separately via my stereo microphone and then process them separately ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Pa_OpenStream(...)` the second to last parameter is a callback function which is where the meat of audio processing is done. It looks like your wrapper is using the function `paStaticCallback`. By looking at the wrapper I see it calls another function `userdata->processingCallBack(...)` which is the last parameter to the `Pa_OpenStream(...)` function.  You've put `this` as the parameter there.

So you need to override the `processingCallback()` function.

There's a bunch more detail in the PortAudio documentation, but the first argument in that function is a void pointer to your input buffer. If you have stereo coming in then each channel will be interleaved.

For example, if you are recording at 16 bits per sample, the first two bytes of that buffer (16 bits) would be the left channel sample, and the next 2 bytes would be the right channel sample. This would then repeat.

You could extract each channel in that callback function.

When I was working with PortAudio, the examples [examples](http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/group__examples__src.html) really helped me.

[Here](http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html) is an example which records audio, stores it in memory and plays it back. Pay close attention to the `recordCallback` and the `playCallback`.

Best of luck.